# ascii codec can't encode character

Tags: python, python-2.7, parse-platform

I'm trying to create a string with special characters from portuguese-brazil (e.g. á, à, â, ç)

```
push_message = 'á'
push_message.decode().encode('utf-8')
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I need to send this to Parse Api, and Parse Api just allows utf8 encoding.
What can I do to solve this?

**EDIT**

When I try

```
push_message.decode('utf-8')
```

I get

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When I try

```
push_message.decode('latin-1')
```

I get

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: So what codec are you decoding *from*? Using the default, ASCII, obviously doesn't work, but you haven't told us anything about what codec your data *is* encoded in.

Comment: If you are trying to create a Unicode literal, you need to use `u'á'` instead, then encode that. You'll have to provide a [PEP 263 codec header](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) in your file if you are to use non-ASCII characters in your source code however.

Comment: You probably want to read the [Python Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) here.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks for the help. I tried and edited my question. Can you check?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Right now I'm typing the data like I wrote in the question. But the script will come from a mysql database.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham updated the question. But I still get the same error.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like this unicode(push_message.decode('utf-8')) @PadraicCunningham can you add an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @FilipeFerminiano, it is fine to  add and accept your own answer if you want.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked like this:

```
unicode(push_message.decode('utf-8'))
```